# Subspace exercises

Tags: linear-algebra

What's the difference between Exercises 13 & 14?

13's $S$ has infinite elements?

14's $S$ has finite elemnets?

And what is the difference for the solutions?

[image]

Comment: Please provide some context what is $\mathcal F (S,F)$?

Comment: "Let S be any nonempty set and F be any field, and let F(S, F) denote the
set of all functions from S to F."

Comment: In both exercises $S$ can be any set (in particular it can have infinitely many elements). The considered subspaces in 14 and 13 are different from each other so the solution will be different too. Your opinion is totally wrong if $S$ has more than 1 element. For example if $S=\{a,b\}$ and $s_0 =a$, then the function $f$ defined by$f(a) =0$ and $f(b)=1$ is non zero, but it is in the subspace. For 14 just take $S$ a finite set and $f$ the constant 1 function. Then it is nonzero and in the subspace.

Comment: $s_0$ doesn't represent all elements in $S$?

Comment: No, it is any **one** element of $S$ (which one isn't specificed, and it shouldn't matter). So in 13), one element $s_0 \in S$ has been singled out, and for a function $f$ to belong to the function space defined there, it must fullfill one condition only: $f(s_0)=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's verify that $A = \{f\in \mathcal{F}(S,F): f(s_0) = 0\}$ is a subspace, so have to be closed under the operation of $ \mathcal{F}(S,F)$ that I call "$+$". $\forall f,g \in A$ for $\alpha f + \beta g$ to be in $A$ $$(\alpha f + \beta g)(s_0) = 0$$
This is indeed true because
$$(\alpha f + \beta g)(s_0) = \alpha f(s_0) + \beta g(s_0) = 0 + 0 = 0$$
so 13 is solved.

---

Second one is a little bit more complicated so again what we have and what we want specifically? $A = \{f\in \mathcal{F}(S,F): f(s) = 0 \ \text{for all but a finite number of element of $S$}\}$ and we hope as above that $\forall f,g \in A$, $\alpha f + \beta g$ is still in $A$. Let
$$S_f:= \{s\in S : f(s) \neq 0\} = \{s^f_1,...,s^f_m\}\\
S_g:= \{s\in S : g(s) \neq 0\} = \{s^g_1,...,s^g_n\}$$

on $B=S_f \cup S_g$, those values (that are finte) are the only possible for $\alpha f + \beta g \neq 0$ since they are only a finite amount, $\alpha f + \beta g \in A$.

Comment: Appriciate it, by the way,  I rember we also need to check if zero is in $A$, right?

Comment: The sum condition is enough because if it's true that $\forall f,g \in A, \alpha f+\beta g \in A \implies \alpha f- \alpha f = 0 \in A$. I should specify that $\alpha,\beta \in F$ and since it's a field we have the inverse of the sum we call $+$.